# Cleaning quote data in Stata

Tags: stata, data-cleaning

I have a problem cleaning my quote data in Stata (see below). I have multiple quotes with the same time stamp and I need to replace all these with a single entry with the median bid and median offer price of these multiple quotes.

Is it possible to do this in Stata and how?

`utcsec` is the time stamp in seconds (34240 (sec.) = 09:30:40 (HH:MM:SS)).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `collapse` and use `utcsec` as the ID:

```
collapse (median) medbid=bid medofr=ofr, by(utcsec)
```

Comment: The code does not have quite the desired output. At somehow it starts the new dataset time variable by 34203 and not 34240. So the median is not calculated correctly.

Comment: And 24203 is not a time stamp in your dataset? If it is: You'll have to specify your question.

Comment: Sorry, the code works perfectly it's just me who missed the time stamp